# How to get all the texts from html page having same id with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, web

I am having webpage with this code:-

```
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2><a id="post_title" class="article-title" href="/post/new/">new</a></h2>
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="/profileview/manish">manish</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
                <small class="text-muted">Sept. 19, 2020, 2:49 a.m.</small>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <img style="height:19px; width:18px;" src="/static/blog/viewicon.png">
                    <p style="float: right; display: inline !important;" id="ViewCount">
                    
                    </p>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content"><p>newnwnewnenwnenwenwewewewewe</p></p>
    </div>
</article>

<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2><a id="post_title" class="article-title" href="/post/post-with-markdown-styling/">Post with Markdown Styling?</a></h2>
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="/profileview/manish">manish</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
                <small class="text-muted">Sept. 15, 2020, 6:46 p.m.</small>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <img style="height:19px; width:18px;" src="/static/blog/viewicon.png">
                    <p style="float: right; display: inline !important;" id="ViewCount">
                    
                    </p>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content"><p>This are the points which you should follow while writting a good blog:- Have a proper Introduction.&nbsp;Be explainatory.&nbsp;Use easy english language.&nbsp;Be consise and clear.&nbsp;Have a go…</p>
    </div>
</article>
------
------
------
```

I am trying to add a text on the tags containing the id `ViewCount` by adding a condition to my javascript code that whenever the `title` feched from the server mathes the title of the page.
Here's my javascript code:-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function()
        {
      $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url: "{% url 'getBlogs' %}",
          success: function(response){
          $("#ViewCount").empty();
          for (var key in response.blogs)
          {
              var fromServerTitle = response.blogs[key].title;
              var fromPageTitle = document.getElementById("post_title").innerText;
              if (fromServerTitle == fromPageTitle) {
                  var temp = response.blogs[key].view_count
                  $("#ViewCount").append(temp);
              }
              //console.log(key);
           }
          },
          error:function(response){
              alert("No Data Found");
          }
      });
        },1000);
    });
```

But with this code, it's checking only for the first `title`, and makes the required changes, but I want this to work for all such `id's`.

Here is the screenshot:-
[image]

Template codes(html):-

```
{% for post in posts %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h2><a id="post_{{post.pk}}" class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.slug %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'blog-profile' name=post.author %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <small class="text-muted">Category</small>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <div style="float:right;">
                <img style="height:19px; width:18px;" src="{% static "blog/viewicon.png" %}">
                    <p style="float: right; display: inline !important;" id="ViewCount">
                    
                    </p>
                </img>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content|truncatechars:200|safe }}</p>
        <hr />
        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm disabled" type="submit">❤</button>
        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm disabled" type="submit"></button>
        <button class="btn btn-light btn-sm disabled" type="submit"></button>
    </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function()
        {
      $.ajax({
          type:'GET',
          url: "{% url 'getBlogs' %}",
          success: function(response){
          $("#ViewCount").empty();
          for (var key in response.blogs)
          {
              var fromServerTitle = response.blogs[key].title;
              var initialstr = "post_"
              var finalstr = initialstr.concat(response.blogs[key].pk)
              var fromPageTitle = document.getElementById(finalstr).innerText;
              if (fromServerTitle == fromPageTitle) {
                  var temp = response.blogs[key].view_count
                  $("#ViewCount").append(temp);
              }
              //console.log(key);
           }
          },
          error:function(response){
              alert("No Data Found");
          }
      });
        },1000);
    });
</script>
```

The output of console:-

```
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
(index):186 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
    at Object.success ((index):186)
    at fire (jquery-3.5.1.js:3496)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.js:3626)
    at done (jquery-3.5.1.js:9786)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.js:10047)
success @ (index):186
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
done @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9786
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10047
load (async)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10066
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):176
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ (index):174
mightThrow @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3762
process @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3830
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3868
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3634
fire @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3496
fireWith @ jquery-3.5.1.js:3626
ready @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4106
completed @ jquery-3.5.1.js:4116
```

Comment: Why in the world would you fetch this separately? You're already rendering the information from the server, so just add it to the template. And while you're at it, fix your ID's. They have to be unique per page.

Comment: The 'viewcount' doesn't update asynchronously, I have to manually refresh the page, So I am using ajax for asynchronization of that value.

Comment: Gotcha. Like I said, fix your ID's: ID's are identifiers, unique per page. You now have invalid HTML. Classes are "things sharing common properties", a "post-title" is a common property, but each title needs to have it's unique ID, like for example the primary key of the post: `id="post-{{ post.pk }}"`. Share the template instead of rendered HTML if you want it to be explained better.

Comment: Hey I am following your approach, but can't actually figure out how to achieve it, I am a beginner in Javascript, It would b of great help if you can please help me with this. I have updated the question with the template.

Comment: One more thing: can you post the output of the ajax call?

Comment: Sure I have added the output of the console log.

Comment: hi can you add op of `response`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using class instead of an id. It should be unique in a page. If you want multiple elements with the same identity then use class with the same name

instead of

```
<tag id="post_title"></tag>
```

use

```
<tag class="post_title"></tag>
```

and in javascript change this line

```
 var fromPageTitle = document.getElementsByClassName("post_title").innerText;
```